# Consuming IMDB api results bad json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, imdb

I have a simple program that consumes IMDB api, I'm getting the result, but it was shown as error because the result is not a structured json.

MovieService.ts

```
export class MovieService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getMovie(movie:string){
    return this.http.get(this.generateURL(movie));
  }
  private generateURL(movie:string){
    return "https://v2.sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/titles/"+movie.charAt(0)+"/"+movie+".json?callback=imdb$"+movie;
  }
}
```

addmovie.component.ts

```
   private _filterMovies(value: string) {
    this.movieService.getMovie(value).subscribe(
      movies => {
        console.log(movies);
        return movies;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addMovieForm.get('movie').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this._filterMovies(val)
    });
  }
```

I'm getting error like

[image]

the response is of bad json. How can I format the json upon receiving? How to solve this? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: set the `responseType` on the `options` paramerter of the `get` request.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964150/getting-a-200-status-but-still-an-error-when-using-post-in-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment96690396_54964150

Answer (score 0):

The result is not `JSON`, but rather [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). It is essentially returning you a script that is trying to execute the callback method specified.

Instead of `http.get()` you should call `http.jsonp(url, "imbdIgnoresThisParam")`.

However, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744369/2577784), the `callback` query string parameter is ignored by IMDB. The answer suggests dynamically creating the expected callback function, whose name contains the title for which you are searching. In that callback you could do a few different things.

1. Use the closure to call / set something in your `MovieService`. This will result in your call to the API throwing an error, as the Angular framework's callback will not be called as expect. You could ignore the error.
2. Try to call the expected Angular callback, `ng_jsonp_callback_<idx>`. This will prevent the API call from throwing, but it may not be reliable. The callback name is dynamic and increments with each `jsonp()` call. You could try to track the number of `jsonp()` calls in your app. And of course, the framework may change and break this solution. Concurrent calls to `getMovie()` may break, as the next one may step on the previous callback on the window. Use with caution!

In typescript, your `getMovie()` function and related helpers might look like so:

```
private imdbData: any = null;
private jsonpIdx = 0;

private setImdb(json: any) {
    this.imdbData = json;
    // or do whatever you need with this
}

getMovie(movie:string) {
    // dynamically create the callback on the window.
    let funcName = `imdb$${movie}`;
    window[funcName] = (json: any) => {
        // use the closure
        this.setImdbData(json);

        // or try to call the callback that Angular is expecting.
        window[`ng_jsonp_callback_${this.jsonpIdx++}`](json);
    }

    // go get your data!
    let url = this.generateURL(movie)
    return this.http.jsonp(url, "ignored").subscribe((json) => {
        // this happens if you successfully trigger the angular callback
        console.log(json);
    }, (err) => {
        // this happens if the angular callback isn't called
        console.log(this.imdbData); // set in closure!
    });
}
```

***Edit for Angular 4***

For `Angular 4`, it looks like you will need to import the `JsonpModule` along with the `HttpModule`. Then, you'd inject `jsonp` just like you'd inject `http` into your service. The call to IMDB becomes `this.jsop.request(url).subscribe(...)` and your dynamic callback name needs to change, too.

```
window[funcName] = (json: any) => {
    // or try to call the callback that Angular is expecting.
    window["__ng_jsonp__"][`__req${this.jsonpIdx++}`]["finished"](json);
}
```

I don't have an Angular 5 or 6 project immediately set up, so hard to say if there are any differences with the callback in those versions.

Sort of a hack, but hope it helps!

Comment: `this.http.jsonp` doesn't do anything. I think it's deprecated.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan What version of `Angular` are you using? My example works just fine with `Angular 7`.

Comment: I'm using the latest version 7.3.x

Comment: I'll check with the JsonpModule. and let you know.

Comment: The `JsonpModule` is deprecated in version 7. Instead, you should use the [jsonp() method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#jsonp) in the `HttpClient`.